# cannot compare ip address in wordpress php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created a custom table to store ip and post id

```
$wpdb->insert('wp_firstvisit',
                     array('IP' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                           'post_id'=>$post_id ),
                     array('%s','%d')
                     );
```

when I try to get the result using

```
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];       
       $result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_firstvisit WHERE post_id =$post_id AND ip=$ip");
```

I don't get any rows

when

```
AND ip=$ip
```

is removed
I get a row

Comment: Wrap your text variables (`strings`) around apostrophes `' '` .

Comment: IP addresses are strings, not numbers, and need to be quoted.

Comment: thank you !! it worked.. can you put it in answer so that I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not going to work, period. an IP address is not a number. It's a string. You're doing what amounts to

```
SELECT ... ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Since that's not a valid number, and it's an unquoted string, you WILL get a syntax error at the sql level:

```
mysql> select 'foo' = 127.0.0.1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near '.0.1' at line 1
                   ^^^^^^
```

Strings **MUST** be quoted:

```
SELECT ... ip = '127.0.0.1';
```